# Should we not use "verbs" instead of "verb"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Our tags are normally using the plural, especially when they are about a grammatical category.

- [articles](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/articles)
- [adverbs](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adverbs)
- [adjectives](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adjectives)
- [modal-verbs](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modal-verbs)

Since the last is not [modal-verb](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modal-verb), should not we also use [verbs](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbs) instead of the actual [verb](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verb)?

Comment: The answer depends on how searches are parsed, I think. Is the string `verb` parsed as a component of the string `verbs`? Caveat: since I know nothing about how tags are used in search, I may have this all wrong.

Comment: I find it somewhat jarring to see the singular for tags. I much prefer the plural. Even this discussion is tagged with "tags" not "tag".

Comment: @ColleenV It is what I think too. A single question could ask about a verb, but all the questions tagged with the same tag are asking about verbs, generally speaking.

Comment: @P.E.Dant When you search for all the questions using a tag, you enter a tag name. You can make a tag as synonym of another one, though.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I understand how to search. I mean to say that I don't understand how strings are processed by the code, since I've never looked under the hood.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I mean that to search all questions tagged verbs, you use `[verbs]`, which finds just that tag, not similar tags. You need of know the tags a site is using.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, I agree.  When our tags have the form of a countable noun phrase, they should be plural.

---

Tag names should have a generic interpretation.  That is, when we use the [modal-verbs](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modal-verbs) tag, we're saying "This question is about modal verbs", referring to the class of modal auxiliary verbs in general.  [And although there are several ways to form a noun phrase with a generic interpretation in English](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html), because we don't use articles in tag names, the only relevant option is the plural generic, as in the following example:

> **Modal auxiliary verbs** are a special type of auxiliary verb used to express meanings such as ability, likelihood, permission, and obligation. These include *will*, *would*, *can*, *could*, *shall*, *should*, *may*, *might*, *must*, *ought*, *need*, and *dare*.

In this example, I've used the plural form to refer to the entire class of modal auxiliaries.  We should do the same thing with our tag names.  When I see a tag with a singular name like [modal-verb](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modal-verb), it feels off to me, like the wrong form of the word has been used.